# GitExtensions cloning gets stuck

Tags: git, github, git-extensions

I am trying to clone a remote GitHub repository using GitExtensions and it always gets stuck at a certain point (roughly on 2/3rd of the way). This time it got stuck at 84%. I thought that since the repository is huge (1GB+) it make take a while to clone but the 84% progress indicator did not move for many minutes, and Receiving objects count remain stalled as well.

[image]

Multiple attempts revealed different points where the process gets stalled.

I spent several hours trying to figure it out but to no avail. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

I am using latest 2.4.7.03 GitExtensions

Comment: Have you tried using command line?

Comment: @linquize yes, same thing - gets stuck all of a sudden.... repeatedly.